# Bash execution error with time

Tags: bash, shell

I am having problems getting Bash syntax and hoping some gurus can help me get it going.

The bash is:

```
(sort | grep po | wc) < /etc/passwd > out ; cat out

exec /usr/bin/time -f "real %e user %U sys %S maxmem %M" (sort | grep po | wc) < /etc/passwd > out; cat out
```

The first line runs as expected. The second line gives the error:

```
./sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./sh: line 2: `exec time (sort | grep po | wc) < /etc/passwd > out'
```

I am trying to get line 1 in the:

```
exec /usr/bin/time -f "real %e user %U sys %S maxmem %M" --Line 1 Solution Here--
```

form.

I've tried about every quoting thing I could think of, and cannot seem to get it going. As a side-note, removing the -f and argument and the preceding exec will allow it to run, but in my scenario, I need them to be in the final solution.

Since I have tried many things here, a response of try putting double-quotes around it, try-this or try that will get a negative vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec /usr/bin/time -f "real %e user %U sys %S maxmem %M" /bin/bash -c 'sort | grep po | wc' < /etc/passwd > out; cat out
```

Thanks to a local co-worker.

Comment: Note that this works because `/usr/bin/time` expects an executable file as its argument, not an arbitrary shell command.